# Django + Pyinstaller Template doesn't exist

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I'm working on pyinstaller to make an executable file from Django project. When i run script its generating Executable file, But when I run EXE from cmd its showing errors as below:

- I have checked settings, etc files in Django project file.
- The template is loading fine when I running on Django default server.
- I have seen many similar issues.But I couldn't find any good answer for those question.

Error:

```
Django version 1.9.13, using settings 'mysite.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
static
C:\Dev\EXE\cookie\dist\mysite\media
http
('Unexpected error:', <class 'django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist'>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "crumbs_mysite\views.py", line 278, in parser
  File "crumbs_mysite\views.py", line 146, in licensevalidation
  File "site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 39, in render_to_response
  File "site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 96, in render_to_string
  File "site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 43, in get_template
django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: activate_license.html

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "crumbs_mysite\views.py", line 278, in parser
  File "crumbs_mysiite\views.py", line 146, in licensevalidation
  File "site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 39, in render_to_response
  File "site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 96, in render_to_string
  File "site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 43, in get_template
django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: activate_license.html
[20/Dec/2017 10:21:09] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 27
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest posting this on pyinstaller.  Have you tried manually adding Django libraries through your spec file?